# I'm trying to link Heroku to our Django site and need help understanding this error log

Tags: python, django, heroku

```
2017-05-15T02:13:43.087131+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2017-05-15T02:14:39.171624+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=newsrank-115.herokuapp.com request_id=18dfe977-391f-4873-88f5-d4d7f7f196a7 fwd="50.131.194.116" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2017-05-15T02:14:39.438971+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=newsrank-115.herokuapp.com request_id=5b31eda6-12e1-42bd-9b1a-53cd95dbc758 fwd="50.131.194.116" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2017-05-15T02:14:48.180441+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2017-05-15T02:14:55.743399+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `gunicorn mysite.wsgi`
2017-05-15T02:14:57.785412+00:00 app[web.1]: [2017-05-15 02:14:57 +0000] [4] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.7.1
2017-05-15T02:14:57.786079+00:00 app[web.1]: [2017-05-15 02:14:57 +0000] [4] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:59306 (4)
2017-05-15T02:14:57.786293+00:00 app[web.1]: [2017-05-15 02:14:57 +0000] [4] [INFO] Using worker: sync
2017-05-15T02:14:57.789917+00:00 app[web.1]: [2017-05-15 02:14:57 +0000] [8] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 8
2017-05-15T02:14:57.794048+00:00 app[web.1]: [2017-05-15 02:14:57 +0000] [8] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
2017-05-15T02:14:57.794050+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2017-05-15T02:14:57.794051+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 578, in spawn_worker
2017-05-15T02:14:57.794052+00:00 app[web.1]:     worker.init_process()
2017-05-15T02:14:57.794052+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 126, in init_process
2017-05-15T02:14:57.794053+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.load_wsgi()
2017-05-15T02:14:57.794054+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 135, in load_wsgi
2017-05-15T02:14:57.794054+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
2017-05-15T02:14:57.794055+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
2017-05-15T02:14:57.794056+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.callable = self.load()
2017-05-15T02:14:57.794056+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 65, in load
2017-05-15T02:14:57.794057+00:00 app[web.1]:     return self.load_wsgiapp()
2017-05-15T02:14:57.794058+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load_wsgiapp
2017-05-15T02:14:57.794058+00:00 app[web.1]:     return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
2017-05-15T02:14:57.794059+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 352, in import_app
2017-05-15T02:14:57.794059+00:00 app[web.1]:     __import__(module)
2017-05-15T02:14:57.794060+00:00 app[web.1]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mysite.wsgi'
2017-05-15T02:14:57.794144+00:00 app[web.1]: [2017-05-15 02:14:57 +0000] [8] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 8)
2017-05-15T02:14:57.820506+00:00 app[web.1]: [2017-05-15 02:14:57 +0000] [4] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
2017-05-15T02:14:57.820607+00:00 app[web.1]: [2017-05-15 02:14:57 +0000] [4] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
2017-05-15T02:14:57.871348+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 3
2017-05-15T02:14:57.886382+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

The app, as previously mentioned is Django and we are trying to host it on Heroku, the app does build. This error shows up on the UI as "application error." Now, one of my other group members said the code (this is all on github) does run locally on his machine, I'm not sure what that means.

I'm afraid I'm pretty new at this, so I could be missing something simple. But I can't find a lot of references to what mysite.wsgi should be in this context.

I should note, we have wsgi.py which looks like this:

```
import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "mysite.settings")

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

I didn't write it, so I'm not sure how right or wrong this is.

Let me know if there is more info I can provide, thanks.

Comment: wsgi.py is not involved in local. That is why it works.

Comment: Hmm ok, that's good to know. But in the larger context of the problem, what does that mean? Is wsgi.py the source of the error?

Answer (score 0):

First, know that wsgi.py is automatically generated when one starts a new project in django. Which means that, it is correct.

Second, your django project cannot reach the server on its own. There must be a bridge between it and the server. That is wsgi.py's job, which does it turning your project into an app.

Third, you must tell your prod server where this wsgi.py is on your path. Something like /home/project/mysite/mysite/.

---

I do not use heroku. But it appears that you must override wsgi.py af follows

```
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
from whitenoise.django import DjangoWhiteNoise

application = get_wsgi_application()
application = DjangoWhiteNoise(application)
```

Comment: I'm sorry, my ability to google isn't working today. I can't find any example of how to add the path. Most examples of wsgi.py look like ours, and this article: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-app-configuration seems to be the best, but we have followed it. Could you be a little bit more specific on how to do these things? Thanks.